# SQL Server update and replace values with values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

**Connections**:

```
id  user_id  connection_info
------------------------------
 1    1      ...
 2    1      ...
 3    2      ...
```

**Lists**:

```
id  connection_id  name
-----------------------
1        1         ...
2        2         ...
3        1         ...
```

I currently have `user_id`'s in the `lists.connection_id` column. I would like to join the `lists` table with the `connections` table by `connections.user_id = lists.connection_id` and then replace the `lists.connection_id` with the corresponding id from the `connections` table.

Comment: so did you try something and fail? if so share your code/errors please. if not, attempt a solution and share it to give folks something to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [UPDATE FROM](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/update-from-select) like this:

```
update l
set l.connection_id = c.id 
from connections c join lists l on c.user_id = l.connection_id
```

Initially you would want to test what you are going to update, running a `SELECT` statement:

```
select l.connection_id as con_old
     , c.id as con_new
     , ... (other cols you might want to check)
from connections c join lists l on c.user_id = l.connection_id
```